# Are there apps that allow two iPhones to communicate directly without the need of any network?

Tags: iphone

I would like to be able to use 2 iPhones as true walkie talkies in the middle of nowhere where there are no networks available. Is this possible? If so, would it be possible to use 3G for this?

Comment: "no networks available" as in no wi-fi networks?

Answer (score 1):

[HeyTell](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/heytell/id352791835?mt=8) works well over 3G. I've used it for years. It's great!

*Answer to comment:*

[Walkie Talkie](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/walkie-talkie-wifi-bluetooth/id361424957?mt=8) for iPhone might do the trick. It uses Wi-Fi or Bluetooth. The Bluetooth range would only be around 30 feet though. You *might* be able to use this one over an ad hoc network, but you'd need a PC or Mac to set that up and even then, I don't know if this app uses its own servers to transmit the messages or if they are transmitted directly.

[Bluetooth Walkie Talkie](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bluetooth-walkie-talkie/id320246525?mt=8) also might do the trick but again, its range is limited.

To answer your question in the comment below there is no way to have walkie talkie like functionality over 3G without having 3G signal from a carrier.

Comment: With no networks I meant that there are just two  iPhones and nothing else. No wifi router, no cellular antennas, no trace of civilization. Ah, and with 3G I meant that the two phones use this channel of communication to communicate between them instead of wifi, because I guess that 3G should have a longer range...

Comment: I've edited my answer with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

I just read of an app called FireChat that was out in 2014.

https://www.technologyreview.com/s/525921/the-latest-chat-app-for-iphone-needs-no-internet-connection/